# Get all commits of a file in a GitHub repo

Tags: github-api

If I use the following url,

`https://api.github.com/repos/raspberrypi/linux/commits?path=drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c`

I get the first 30 commits. But that file has around 3000 commits. How can I get all the commits to this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like the following code after looking at [Pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) on the GitHub API documentation. But, you have to be careful about the API request rate as discussed [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting).

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/raspberrypi/linux/commits?access_token=<your github user OAuth token>&path=drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c'
commits = []

i = 1
r = requests.get(url + '&per_page=100&page=' + str(i))
while len(r.json()) != 0:
    commits.extend(r.json())
    i += 1
    r = requests.get(url + '&per_page=100&page=' + str(i))

with open('commits.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(commits, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query for all commits associated with a given file:

```
var stats = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var path in allPaths)
{
    var request = new CommitRequest { Path = "path/to/file.cs" };
    var commitsForFile = await client.Repository.Commit.GetAll(Owner, Name, request);
    stats.Add(path, commitsForFile.Length);
}
```

This code uses [Octokit](https://octokit.github.io/) that is officially maintained and supported by GitHub. All Octokit libraries are released under the MIT license which means they can be modified and used in any project.

Taken from - https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1293

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks! Can I do this without using Octokit?

Comment: @josh I guess you can take a look at how is GetAll method implemented and start from there